# Import an existing s3 from aws using modules

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I have a module to create s3, from the module I created a bucket and in aws I created another manually, I'm trying to import it.

```
main.tf - of the module that is called "s3"
```

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  count         = var.create_bucket && length(var.s3_bucket_names) > 0 ? length(var.s3_bucket_names) : 0
  bucket        = "${var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]}-bucket"
  force_destroy = var.force_destroy
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_access" {
  count  = var.create_bucket && length(var.s3_bucket_names) > 0 ? length(var.s3_bucket_names) : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3[count.index].id

  block_public_acls       = var.block_public_acls
  block_public_policy     = var.block_public_policy
  ignore_public_acls      = var.ignore_public_acls
  restrict_public_buckets = var.restrict_public_buckets
}
```

`main.tf`

```
 module "s3" {

  count = var.create_bucket ? 1 : 0

  source          = "./modules/s3"
  s3_bucket_names = var.s3_bucket_names
  create_bucket   = var.create_bucket

  force_destroy = var.force_destroy

  block_public_acls       = var.block_public_acls
  block_public_policy     = var.block_public_policy
  ignore_public_acls      = var.ignore_public_acls
  restrict_public_buckets = var.restrict_public_buckets

}
```

In my tfvar I have the s3 that I created initially, I thought that the new s3 that I want to import should be added to the tfvars...

```
tfvars
```

```
create_bucket = true
s3_bucket_names = [
  "my-k-frontend-test",
  "my-k-frontend-test-2"

]

block_public_acls       = true
block_public_policy     = true
ignore_public_acls      = true
restrict_public_buckets = true
```

and then I run the command to import and it says that it was done correctly..

```
$ terraform import -var-file=test.tfvars module.s3.aws_s3_bucket.s3 my-k-frontend-test-2-bucket
```

```
data.aws_subnet.subnets_id["subnet-xxxxxxxxxx"]: Read complete after 1s [id=subnet-xxxxxxxxxx]
data.aws_subnet.subnets_id["subnet-xxxxxxxxxx"]: Read complete after 1s [id=subnet-xxxxxxx]
data.aws_subnet.subnets_id["subnet-xxxxxxxxx"]: Read complete after 1s [id=subnet-xxxxxxxx]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

but when executing the plan it is as if it were not in the state file yet..

```
data.aws_subnet.subnets_id["subnet-xxxxxx"]: Read complete after 1s [id=subnet-xxxxx]
data.aws_subnet.subnets_id["subnet-xxxxxxx"]: Read complete after 1s [id=subnet-xxxxxx]
module.s3[0].aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.s3_access[0]: Refreshing state... [id=my-k-frontend-test-2-bucket]
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

which are the aws_s3_bucket and aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block resources for the my-k-frontend-test-2 bucket..

Something that I saw strange is that in the plan it does show the s3 module but in the import it only shows the data that I have in the project

*When I create the s3 I add the suffix -bucket through the module, so when importing I do it with the full name of how it is created in aws, which also has the suffix -bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of your output, I believe the issue is that you have imported your manually-created bucket over top of the Terraform-created bucket in the state file. (You can open and inspect the state file for yourself to see what's going on, it's JSON).

To get to this conclusion, I'm assuming that `my-k-frontend-test-bucket` is the bucket you created using TF, and `my-k-frontend-test-2-bucket` is the one you created manually.

To import it properly, you need to index into your bucket resource list properly:

```
$ terraform import -var-file=test.tfvars module.s3[0].aws_s3_bucket.s3[1] my-k-frontend-test-2-bucket
                                                                      ^^^
                                                             Note the indexing here
```

The `aws_s3_bucket.s3` resource is created as a list rather than a single item because you've specified it using a `count` parameter.

You'll probably want to also import the original TF-created bucket back into the first slot of that list, too.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I was not accessing the position of the bucket, in addition to that you must take into account if you have another resource in the module, for example `aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block` you must also import that resource to the specific s3, thank you so much!!